# Openshift hosting app to different location

Tags: openshift, web-hosting

I have already hosting my application in openshift, hosting location is `America/New York`, and openshift has recently started giving support for Europe region, i have customers mostly from India and my web application focus on Indian customers only.

Openshift has given the option to change the location from America to Europe on customer preference.
my question is,

1. is there any difference interms of hosting location
2. if i want to change my location to Europe which relatively closer to India, how can i choose location while deploying my app and any limitations.

Note: my app is in PROD, and we have users accessing our web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a KB article about how to move your application from the us-east to the eu-west location: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203265710-How-can-I-move-an-existing-application-from-the-US-aws-us-east-1-hosting-region-to-the-European-aws-eu-west-1-hosting-region-

Response times should be better since it is closer to the geography that your application is targeting, but keep in mind that you can only select the eu-west location for small.highcpu, medium, and large gears.